# htaccess How to extract slash from initial request

Tags: .htaccess

I'm not so professional in .htaccess rules. How to do the following in .htaccess:

- Initial: `.../upi.html/?id=1&amt=1`
- To be redirected to:  `.../upi.html?id=1&amt=1`

Answer (score 1):

To remove the trailing slash you can use the following in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

The above checks if the requested URL ends with a slash (/) and if the requested filename is not a directory. If both conditions are met, the trailing slash is removed. This is currently set as a temporary redirect (302). If this works as you expect then changes to a 301 redirect which makes it permanent.